# How to create folder name or file name with special characters like \ / : * ? " < > |

Tags: windows, windows-10, filenames

My problem is that, I can not give name of my folder or file with special characters like \ / : * ? " < > | in windows based O.S.
This is very important for me, that giving name of file/folder which contain this type of characters.

I already search and refer so many site,for this problems but all are hopeless.
I also read Microsoft support page, they suggest use other characters. This is its link, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177506

I already try Alt button + ASCII code number of this type of special characters, from numpad key, just example rename file/folder and press Alt+60 (for < characters) Still it giving message that, A filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
\ / : * ? " < > |

Suggest me suitable solution so that I can give name of my file/folder with this type of special characters.

Comment: Just curious: what do you need it for?

Comment: @ kamil This is for give name of my file/folder, and one challenging task for me.

Comment: @ PIMP_JUICE_IT I already did it, (literalString -literalPath but still not get success.

Comment: even if you *could* create files with these characters, no program would be able to open or save them.

Comment: @keltari Its okk,, but i have to create file/folder name with these characters. For access and run may be i will find other plan..

Comment: – How can I lick my elbow? – You can't. – But I have to. – You can break your arm and try but your arm will be useless then. – I don't care, I just need to lick my elbow.

Comment: I was able to name a folder `⧹ ⧸ ﹕ ✱ ﹖ ‹ ›`, which contains characters that merely look like the ones Windows won't allow. @KamilMaciorowski , lick that!

Comment: @LonnieBest Congratulations, you have licked a prosthetic elbow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### This is very important for me, naming of file/folder which contain these characters.

It may be important to you, but you will have to let this go and find a different way to solve your problem.

These characters are not allowed by the Windows OS function calls that handle filenames.

They are specifically not allowed because they have another use:

- <kbd>\</kbd> - Reserved for use as a path separator and [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) character
- <kbd>/</kbd> - Reserved for use as a path separator
- <kbd>:</kbd> - Reserved for use as a drive name delimiter
- <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>?</kbd> - Reserved for use as [wildcard](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) characters
- <kbd>"</kbd> - Reserved for use to [quote](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) names containing spaces
- <kbd><,</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>|</kbd> - Reserved for use as command [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) operators

You can, of course, create files with names containing these characters using a different operating system (as long as that operating system can read/write a Windows file system).

However, you will be unable do do anything with those files using any Windows programs and they will not understand the file names and will generate errors.

---

#### Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces

> **Naming Conventions**
>
> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and
>   process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file
>   system:
>
> ...
>
> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:
>
>   ```
>   < (less than)
>   > (greater than)
>   : (colon)
>   " (double quote)
>   / (forward slash)
>   \ (backslash)
>   | (vertical bar or pipe)
>   ? (question mark)
>   * (asterisk)
>   ```
> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters
>     are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File
>     Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Source [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

#### But I really want to do this anyway.

Install [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) and use `touch`.

I haven't tested all the possibilities but the following work:

```
touch :
touch \|
touch \"
touch \>
```

Example output:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test/impossible
$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 DavidPostill None 0 Aug 10 21:03 '"'
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 DavidPostill None 0 Aug 10 21:02 :
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 DavidPostill None 0 Aug 10 21:02 '|'
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 DavidPostill None 0 Aug 10 21:07 '>'
```

As you can see they are not usable in Windows:

```
F:\test\impossible>dir
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test\impossible

10/08/2016  21:07    <DIR>          .
10/08/2016  21:07    <DIR>          ..
10/08/2016  21:03                 0 
10/08/2016  21:02                 0 
10/08/2016  21:07                 0 
10/08/2016  21:02                 0 
               4 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,772,601,536,512 bytes free
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it is little bit helpful, but my problem remain same.. I think any other super user way to rename with these special character.

Comment: @Kirit You can create files with those characters but Windows cannot do anything with them and you will get errors when you try and use those files from within Windows.

Comment: @ DavidPostill Ohh, How to create file name with those characters. I don't mind if it give error, but now task is give these type of character name.. For access this file i will use other linux based os

Comment: @Kirit I already told you in the answer "You can, of course, create files with names containing these characters using a different operating system (as long as that operating system can read/write a Windows file system)."

Comment: @Kirit You can also install cygwin and use `touch` (but I haven't tested all the possibilities)

Comment: @Kirit See updated answer. You can create files with those characters but they are not usable.

Comment: @Devid thanks, for your help, but I need (I plan) to give folder name with out any other Linux based os use.

Comment: @Kirit I already told you **it is not possible**.

Comment: What's up with the DIR output? It looks like the characters have been mapped to high unicode. Is that true (or is it an artifact of the representation on SE), and if so, does it work in reverse, i.e. can I create a file using the unicode codepoint and read it in Cygwin as a reserved character?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I've no idea. That's what it showed when I tried it as an experiment.

Comment: In what sense are those files "not usable in Windows"? Clearly windows can see them; can it read and write to them? Besides the funky printing, are there any errors you get with attempting to use the files?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It appears `cmd` can read and write them, although I had to use <tab> or wildcards to select the file. With explorer I can right click and do stuff.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It doesn't help the OP though as the names don't appear as he wishes from the Windows side of the fence.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, strictly speaking he never said that they needed to *appear* correct, only that he wanted to create files with the reserved characters. ;)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That's true. He can always accept my answer if that is the case :)

Comment: @DavidPostil After referring some document and refer duplicate question answer i feel you are right..

Answer (score 4):

Build your own font set. Replace some of the characters you do not use with the images of the reserved characters.

Comment: That or using lookalike characters. With Unicode, anything is possible. 

Comment: @ Craig620 May be it will not possible, for me. can give me some hint for it.

Comment: Not sure, just a crazy idea that came to mind. Maybe there is a Stack Exchange forum for typography or publishing you could ask?

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, you cannot create files with those characters. There's no solution, these characters are prohibited by the Win32 API.

> Win32 is a subset of the POSIX namespace and is case insensitive. It
>   uses all the Unicode characters, except: '"' '*' '/' ':' '<' '>' '?'
>   '\' '|' N.B. Names cannot end with Dot '.', or Space ''.

-- http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf

Comment: NTFS is not the problem. (In fact it allows these characters just fine – it _had to_, for Interix support.) The problem is Windows itself, that is, the restrictions are imposed by Win32 APIs no matter what the underlying FS is.

Comment: @grawity, you appear to be correct based on my further investigations. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I think NTFS is not problem. It must have some solution. When i access NTFS drive from Linux based O.S than may be i can type these type of characters.

Comment: "Names cannot end with Dot". Incorrect. You can file names ending in `.`. You just can't do much with them from `cmd` :)

Comment: @Kirit No. See my answer.

Comment: @David It is also important to give folder name with these special characters.Now my focus on give folder with these special characters.

Comment: @Kirit You have been told many times **it is not possible**.

Comment: @DavidPostill: You need to use the `\\?\C:\...` naming for that, too – Win32 strips all trailing dots, afaik.

Comment: @grawity Or `touch` in cygwin ;p