# How to show special characters in filename in Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, filenames, special-characters

**How can I inspect the characters of a file name in Windows 10** ?

I have some files which contains some 'space' characters, and other who contain some 'non-breaking-space' characters. And maybe some with a mix of the two, or others who contains other "space-like" characters.

Another example would be the latin 'c' character, VS the cyrillic 'с' character.

I need to know how to inspect those characters, when I have the need.

**To reproduce** a simplified sample of the problem I am facing, you can use this in a PowerShell :

```
mkdir 'test space'
mkdir 'test space'
dir test*space
```

(the second one is with a non-breaking space, you can write one with Alt + 0160 on numpad)

Here is the output on PowerShell :

[image: example of folder with special char versus 'normal' chars]

To be clear, I don't just want to differentiate between 2 nearly identical names.

I would like to have a way of knowing if one of the space in any filename / folder name is a special space (and which one it is), and same for other characters like 'c' : is it a latin 'c' or a cyrillic 'c' or some other graphically identical thing ? And which one ?

---

I have found different info on how to *search* for filenames with special characters : [Trying to search filenames with special characters in windows explorer (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1230033/trying-to-search-filenames-with-special-characters-in-windows-explorer-windows)

or how to *create* one :

[How to create folder name or file name with special characters like \ / : * ? " < > |](https://superuser.com/questions/1112132/how-to-create-folder-name-or-file-name-with-special-characters-like/1112160)

[How would I go about creating a filename with invalid characters such as :?> ?](https://superuser.com/questions/187469/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-filename-with-invalid-characters-such-as)

But, if I've read correctly, it doesn't seem that the answers give a way to **see** the special characters.

Comment: Note : I understand I can search for filenames containing a specific special characters, but this solution does not scale for and is valid *only if I already know* which special unicode characters I am looking for. So, that's why I am looking for a solution that allows me to visualize the details of all filename characters.

Comment: The simplest way I see is to use a custom font. Search for the font where the symbols in question differs (for example, cyrillic symbols are 1 pixel down, hard space is shown as 1-pixel dot, etc...).

Comment: That could be a possible answer, and fairly easy, do you you want to turn this comment into one ?

Comment: No. It's an advice, not solution. If only I had a link to such font... but I have not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to be *certain* what characters are hidden in a filename is to [examine the volume table of contents](https://tierradatarecovery.co.uk/examining-the-raw-data-on-your-hard-drive-with-a-hex-editor/) (TOC) in a hex editor. Any given font you use to view a filename might be missing or have duplicates of a given character. For example, of the two files below that appear to be `unins batt.png`, one has a space and the other a non-breaking space in the name.

[image: Space vs. NBS in filename]

In a [hex editor](https://www.mitec.cz/hex.html), the difference is obvious: `0x00FF2000` as opposed to `0x00F5A000`.

[image: VTOC in MiTec HexEdit]

Comment: That was the "hex editor" answer I was hoping. As a complement, do you know any way to locate the entry address for some file in the TOC, other from searching for a part of it (like "batt") ?

Comment: @Pacopaco, since the FAT32 root directory isn’t stored at a predefined location, I did just as you stated, searching on part of a filename. There are forensic tools to examine the TOC and links in detail, but I went for quick-and-dirty. Sorry about that. If someone knows of a free tool, please post it here.